# How to filter with data taken from $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am currently trying to aggregate list of documents by filtering them with data taken with `$lookup`

```
Product.aggregate([
{
        $lookup: {
          from: "categories",
          localField: "category",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "category",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$category" }])
```

I was hoping adding `{ $match: { "category.left": {$gte: 3}} },` would be able to get all of the products with categories that's `left` property is greater than specified, but so far I get nothing. what would be the solution for this?

### category documents

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), "left" : 1, "right" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d7"), "left" : 3, "right" : "8"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d8"), "left" : 4, "right" : "5"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d9"), "left" : 6, "right" : "7" }
```

### product documents

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc129120"), "category": ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc129121"), "category": ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d7")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc129122"), "category": ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d8")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc129123"), "category": ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d9") }
```

I was expecting to get

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc129121"), "category": ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d7")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc129122"), "category": ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d8")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc129123"), "category": ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d9") }
```

for my response

Comment: add `brands` collection documents..

Comment: @turivishal sorry, I should have removed brands there as that one isn't relevant for this situation

Comment: so your query looks good just add $match stage, see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gF_PSZho0xT)